# How to create own help to a class or to a method

Tags: java, android, manual

my question: Is it possible to add some information (description) to a class or to a method, that would be see from eclipse when I use this class or the method in a code. And how?

As well as the black box in the picture below, I would like to have own description next to my own method.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about [Javadoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc)?

Comment: Can you edit your question and elaborate your question more?

Comment: please specify question in better way.

Comment: Just a language issue with this question. Tried to fix it. @Meph please be careful with your questions. Upvote this once.

Comment: sorry, I'm going to edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to add some information (description) to a class or to
>   a method

=> Yes Its possible to comment block (Javadoc style).

For example:

```
/**
This method is used for bla bla bla...
@author Paresh Mayani
@Date 16th April
**/
public void display()
{
.....
.....
}
```

And this above comment will popup in Yellow notes while you are implementing.